# A single Android layout xml file that handles slightly different portrait and landscape layouts?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I get that if you want a different layout for portrait and landscape, you set up a different xml file for each orientation.

What if the changes are very small, and you don't want to have to maintain 2 sets of layout files every time a design changes?  Is there any way to say in a single layout xml file:

if (portrait) ...

else ...

Comment: Well you could have values that differ on orientation changes, such as sizing.  Or you could do it pragmatically, so that on rotation if modify the layout.

Comment: You could separate the different components of your layout into separate layouts (with `include`), and you'd have 2 versions of the same layout (portrait and landscape) only for that very small part of the UI.

Comment: As @mbmc pointed out, you don't need to override the entire layout. Using `include` you can extract only 1 View to redefine

Answer (score 0):

depends on the changes... sometimes is better to do a new layout than to do all programatically but you can do that if yes

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //do the code
}
else{
        //do the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with changes programmatically rather than with a couple of xml layouts, you could have a pair of boolean attributes that will let you query at run time whether you're in portrait or landscape.

e.g. in values\dimens.xml

`<bool name="is_landscape">false</bool>`

and in values-land\dimens.xml

`<bool name="is_landscape">true</bool>`

Then you can query this at run time with:

`boolean isLandscape = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape);`

Comment: can you use that is_landscape property in another xml file?  that's what I want to do

Comment: It should work fine in any xml file inside the values or values-land folders.

Comment: I feel like this might be helpful, but how - inside a layout file - can I check if this flag is set, and change the layout based on if it is true or false?

Comment: No, you won't be able to do any logic based around that particular variable in xml, but it might be possible to create different styles for portrait and landscape that allow you to set certain UI elements to visible or gone. To use the is_landscape property, you will need to find all of your views and set their properties in code rather than in xml.